# what are the current build tools available today which are language agnostic?

Tags: gradle, rake, buildr

Our current system is in .Net world and we are in the process of moving to FeF world (Angular) and we might keep the back end either in .net or change it to some flavor of JVM. We do not know about the server side yet but for sure, we will keep it as .Net for some time till we sort out the technology issues.

One thing I want to do during this time to do is build a CI system with language agnostic build tools. We use NAnt/MSBuild today. **I would like to know as of now what are all active build tools out there, which can work with any language?** I did find the following, but not sure how many are all active today. I am not trying to find which is best or not, all I want to know is the tool set and I will evaluate them based on our project requirements. I want to make sure I did not miss some build tool because I do not know the Java world.

Current list

- Make
- Rake
- Gradle
- BuildR

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291252/language-agnostic-build-management-system) but it is 5 years old.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly if you look at the visual studio files in a text editor you will see that they are indeed build scripts. They are actually msbuild.